# Packed Items at Indian Customs

Tags: india, customs-and-immigration, electronic-items, indian-citizens, gifts

I am travelling back to India soon. Just eager to know, if the packed items carried in checked in or carry-on luggage will face a problem at Indian Customs?

I did purchase few things in form of cosmetics/grooming  (not exceeding $25 each) as gift items for my friends/family and I am willing to keep the packing. I didn't keep the bill/receipt as well.

It's my first travel experience. I am sorry if it sounds silly question.

Comment: What's with electronic items tag? is it cosmetics or electronics?

Comment: Or both ???????

Comment: Includes both but very lower cost like i said even less then $20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on multiple factors but mainly:

- Your age
- How long you have stayed abroad
- Where you are coming back from

Having said that, the rules are quite clear. [Here is a quick .pdf guide that will tell you the maximum worth of goods you are bringing in to the country](http://www.cbec.gov.in/trvler-guide_ason22may2013.pdf).

[If you want more detailed documentation, check out this rule sheet.](http://www.cbec.gov.in/customs/cs-act/formatted-htmls/bgge-rules1998-ason-march%2713.htm)

If you are saying that the the goods that you are bringing in to the country do not exceed a couple hundred dollars, you don't even need to declare it with customs and so it does not matter whether they are in your luggage or hand carry.

Comment: Hi karancan, both links are dead...